# Calculate height of new shape created by Jquery 3D rotation plugin

Tags: jquery, math, 3d, shapes

I am using [this jquery plugin](http://www.zachstronaut.com/projects/rotate3di/#demos) to rotate a div.
I want to know the math equation to calculate the height of the new shape. By 'new height" I mean the height of the top most part of the shape to the most bottom part of the shape, but in a straight line from top to bottom. I want to change my container DIV height to match the shape's new height.

Comment: Could you clarify with a small diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin works by skewing over the Y-direction by some degrees, and scaling in the X-direction by some factor.

The skewing degrees moves linearly from 0 to 360. The scaling moves linearly from 100% to 0%, and back to 100%. The definition of the transformations are:

```
Skew((x,y),degreeX,degreeY) -> (x + tan(degreeX)*y, y + tan(degreeY)*x)

Scale((x,y),scaleX,scaleY) -> (x*scaleX, y*scaleY)

Scale(Skew((x,y),0,deg),scale,0) = (x*scale, y + tan(deg)*x)
```

Transforming a div of size `W × H`, the maximum height of the div would be at 89°:

```
2*Scale(Skew((W/2,H/2),0,89),1/180,0) = (W*(1/180), H + tan(89°)*W)

New width = W*(1/180) = W/180
New height = H + tan(89°)*W ≈ H + 57.29*W
```

This is probably a lot higher than you imagined.

---

You can achieve a more realistic rotation, by skewing by `atan(0.5)*sin(deg)` degrees, and scaling by a factor of `cos(deg)`. This would give a maximum height of `H + W/2` at 90°.